# Link_to and routing in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have my link_to link to localhost:3000/questions/1 but right now it's linking to localhost:3000/questions

Link to code

```
<%= link_to "Your Q's", your_questions_path %>
```

Routes.rb file

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/" => "main_app#index"
  get "/location" => "location#location"
  post "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/index" => "location#index"
  get "/location/directions" => "location#directions"

  root to: 'questions#index'

  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :questions, except: [:new] do
  resources :answers, only: [:create]
  end

  get '/register', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  # get '/questions/your_questions', to: 'questions#your_questions' original
  get '/questions/:id', to: 'questions#show'
  get '/questions', to: 'questions#your_questions', as: 'your_questions'
  get '/search', to: 'questions#search'
```

Comment: Have you tried running `rake routes` in the terminal to see how these routes are actually evaluated?

Comment: yea did rake routes i dont think anything helped

Comment: Did you read it? Perhaps paste the output here so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<%= link_to "Your Q's", question_path(1) %>
```

If an id is any way dynamical, you will need to update your question with more details about objects you have defined in your controller/views

Comment: no that answer doesnt work, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the renamed route for each action, i.e.:

```
get '/questions/:id', to: 'questions#show', as: 'your_question'
get '/questions', to: 'questions#your_questions', as: 'your_questions'
```

This allows the use of `your_question_path(1)`, for example, to refer to GET 'questions/1'

You can also do this with resourceful routing:

```
  resources :questions, as: 'your_questions', only: :show
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following command:

```
 get '/questions', to: 'questions#your_questions', as: 'your_questions'
```

The **as:** part is saying: "Hey Rails, my man, create a method called your_questions_path". This method will generate a string, which represents a URL: '/questions'. Which, if clicked, in the link, will take the user to (the **to:** part): 'questions#your_questions'. Pretty easy, right?

So it's working alright. What this action should be doing though is just listing all the questions from that user. Your routes are fine IMO. The action 'your_questions' is the one who should adjust to show all the questions from the current user.

You see, the route to show a question by it's id is the one above:

```
get '/questions/:id', to: 'questions#show'
```

Comment: so in exchange of what i need to put what?

Comment: Just implement your method your_questions in the QuestionController to list all the questions from that user.

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

Further to the other answers, you really need to clean up your `routes` file:

```
  #config/routes.rb

  root to: 'questions#index'
  get '/search', to: 'questions#search'

  resources :location do
     collection do
       match :index, via: [:get, :post]
       get :directions
       get "/", action: "location"
     end
  end

  resources :answers, only: [:create]
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create], path_names: { new: "register" }
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy], path_names: { destroy: "signout", new: "login",  } do
     collection do
        delete :logout, action: :destroy
     end
  end
  resources :questions, except: [:new] do
     collection do
        get "questions", action: :your_questions
     end
  end
```

You need to remember that Rails' routing structure is [resource-based](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), meaning that every route you create needs to be based around a resource (`controller#action`).

Your routes were so haphazard it was unreal - by far the best thing you can do is keep your routes centred around your controllers / objects, adding extra routes only as required

[image]

--

**Fix**

To fix your problem you need to call the `show` action of your `QuestionsController`. As described above, this can either be done by linking to the `show` route, or if you wanted to use a custom route, to use that

I would do the following

Make sure your routes are constructed correctly (probably 90% of your issue right there), and then ensure you're able to call the correct path:

```
<%= link_to "Your Q's", question_path(1) %>
```

However, the problem you have is that will only show `question 1` - if you want to show "your Questions", you'll be best using the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do 
   collection do
      get :your_questions
   end
end

<%= link_to "Your Q's", your_questions_path %>
```